# Unequal arm length Michelson Interferometer Light Intensity

Tags: optics, electric-fields, intensity

Imagine a Michelson interferometer with unequal arm length. A laser beam with an electric field of the form $$E(t,z) = 2E\cos(ωt+kz)$$ is incident on a 50/50 beam-splitter. The first arm is of length `L` and the other arm is slightly with length `L+ΔL`. The 2 electric fields, reflected - R and transmitted-T) are of the form $$E_{R} = E\cos(ωt)$$ and $$E_{T} = Ecos(ωt+2kΔL)$$ Their intensity at the interferometer screen when recombining is proportional to $$ I \propto [E_{R} + E_{T}]^2$$ yielding $$I \propto E^2+E^2\cos(2kΔL)$$ My professor then proceeds and says, $I_{out}=\frac{I_{0}}{2}[1+\cos(2kΔL)]$. The question is, since $I \propto E^2$

I do not get from where the factor of two in the denominator comes from. Any insight is appreciated!

Edit: Following Ruslan's comment, I am not talking about a contradiction. I am just asking if someone knows a full derivation of this in order to bring out the factor of 2.

Comment: $I\propto E^2$ means there exists $r$ such that $I=rE^2$. Since you've not specified the value of $r$, there's no contradiction between your expression and the professor's one.

Comment: your definition of your incident E-field is $E_0=2E$. So $I_0=4E^2$. So by definition you should have $I_0/4$[...], which is wrong. The confusion lies with the fact that a 50/50 splitter will split your energy in 2, not the field. The field is reduced by a $\sqrt{2}$ factor. Then everything falls into place.